# console display question marks on same code before storing it to char*

Tags: c++, character

tnis is a long function but the key problem is in the char* variables..
**the function was working fine before i have trasformed it to store the data instead of print to console.

i have tried to use `char[]` instead of `char*` that's when i got some buffer overrun error, so now as it is allocated, it shows ??? all over the console.
what is the correct way to concat and use `char*` on `puts();`

```
MySystemInfo Msi;
puts(Msi.getOsInfo());

char* MySystemInfo::getOsInfo()
{
    OSVERSIONINFOEX osver;
    BOOL bOsVersionInfoEx;
    HKEY hKey;
    LONG lRet;
    char* RtTmpOsInfo= (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*70);
    char* s1=(char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
    char* s2=(char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*50);


    // Try calling GetVersionEx() using the OSVERSIONINFOEX structure.
    // If that fails, try using the OSVERSIONINFO structure.
    ZeroMemory(&osver, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX));
    osver.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX);
    if(!(bOsVersionInfoEx = GetVersionEx((OSVERSIONINFO *) &osver)))
    {
        osver.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO);
        if(!GetVersionEx((OSVERSIONINFO *) &osver))
            return "";
    }


    switch (osver.dwPlatformId)
    {
        //Test for the Windows NT product family.
        case VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT:

            if(osver.dwMajorVersion <4> BUFSIZE) return "";
            sprintf( s1,"v%d.%d "+ osver.dwMajorVersion, osver.dwMinorVersion);
            // Test for the specific product family.
            if(osver.dwMinorVersion==0){
                if(osver.dwMajorVersion == 5) sprintf(s2,"Microsoft Windows 2000\n");
                else if(osver.dwMajorVersion == 6) sprintf(s2,"Microsoft Windows Vista\n");
            }

            else if(osver.dwMinorVersion==1){
                if(osver.dwMajorVersion == 5) sprintf(s2,"Microsoft Windows XP\n");
                else if(osver.dwMajorVersion == 6) sprintf(s2,"Microsoft Windows 7\n");
            }
            else if(osver.dwMinorVersion==2){
                if(osver.dwMajorVersion == 5) sprintf(s2,"Microsoft Windows Server 2003 family\n");
            }
            else sprintf(s2,"unknown OS\n");
        break;

    }
    strcat(RtTmpOsInfo,s1);     
    strcat(RtTmpOsInfo,s2);

    //lRet/* = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\WindowsNT\\CurrentVersion\\Hotfix\\Q246009", 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey);
    //  printf("Service Pack 1 (Build %d)\n", osver.dwBuildNumber & 0xFFFF);*/

    return RtTmpOsInfo;
}
```

Comment: In C++ you should use `new` and `delete`, not `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: You might want to turn the `+` into a comma: `sprintf( s1,"v%d.%d "+ osver.dwMajorVersion...`

Comment: What is `if(osver.dwMajorVersion <4> BUFSIZE)` supposed to mean?

Comment: In C++ you should make your programming life easier using proper **string classes** instead of C-like raw buffers/pointers (and related unsafe string management functions).

Comment: @joshpoley sharp eyes !

Comment: @Barmar i have no idea,@ the header it's `#define BUFSIZE 80`, i think it says no i think i still have no idea..

Comment: You wrote the code, what did you intend it to do?

Comment: I could understand if you write `if(osver.dwMajorVersion < 4)`, but why did you add `> BUFSIZE` in there?

Comment: @Barmar no i did not it's stolen from some source on internet, i have just changed it, i think it's originally in c.

Comment: Then you must have made a copying error. I doubt they wrote that. Do you have a link to the original?

Comment: You shouldn't return a literal string `""` when the function also returns a dynamically-allocated string. The caller needs to free the string when they're done with it, and freeing the literal is not allowed.

Comment: @Barmar i have done CTR Z all the way back to paste . same as source, i will check my chrome history give me a minute plz

Comment: @Barmar i think it's ainchent , here's the link ! >http://www.tenouk.com/cpluscodesnippet/getwindowsosversion.html

Comment: Wow, that line is really in there. Maybe it was an error that happened when they converted the source code to HTML. Because it makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @Barmar tell me what you think about it

Comment: @barmar  what is your mail /skype ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::strcat` looks for a null byte in the destination buffer. The buffer `RtTmpOsInfo` is pointing to is uninitialized, though, so calling `std::strcat` on it results in undefined behavior.

Instead of the first `std::strcat` call, use just

```
strcpy(RtTmpOsInfo,s1);
```

or, if your unsure whether `s1` actually has a null byte,

```
strncpy(RtTmpOsInfo, s1, SOME_CONSTANT);
```

where `SOME_CONSTANT` is the maximal number of bytes written to `RtTmpOsInfo`.

Comment: The solution is to use `strcpy()` the first time.

Comment: He filled in `s1` and `s2` using `sprintf()`, so they're guaranteed to have null terminators.

Comment: Another solution is `sprintf(RtTmpOsInfo, "%s%s", s1, s2)`

Comment: @barmar ..nice one barmar, but both the approach of `sprintf` as u show and @cad . still there is one problem as `s2` overrides `s1` or something cause only `s2` successfully stored into `RtTmpOsInfo` which now display ok on screen, just without the `s1` value - `v6.1`

Answer (score 0):

Since you marked this question as `[c++]` and not `[c]`, I would suggest you to abandon the use of hard to read/use/maintain raw C-like string buffers (and related unsafe string functions like `strcat`), and instead use a **convenient C++ string class**.

For example, you could use `std::string` and you could return a `std::string` instance instead of a raw `char*` (with all the problems associated to the lifetime of a `char*` raw pointer!).

You could concatenate substrings using `std::string`'s overloaded **`operator+`** and **`+=`**, in a very intuitive natural way.

Or you could use the **`std::ostringstream`** class, and build the whole string using the stream semantics, with `operator<<`.

In this case, once your whole string is composed, you could just call the **`ostringstream::str()`** method to get a `std::string` instance to be returned to the caller.

In this way, your code will be much simpler, clearer and less bug-prone.

Comment: i am trying to save calls to cpu, be as minimal as i can be. not using string as  a practice

Comment: @RajFelix: _Premature optimization_ is the root of all evil.